# Fluent Bit tail input plugin high memory usage and logs not being forwarded on Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, logging, newrelic, fluent-bit

I have Fluent Bit 1.9 installed on a Windows Server 2019 host with the following configuration to forward logs generated by .NET apps to New Relic.

*C:\Program Files\fluent-bit\conf\fluent-bit.conf*

```
@INCLUDE new-relic-fluent-bit.conf
```

*C:\Program Files\fluent-bit\conf\new-relic-fluent-bit.conf*

```
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Tag iotprocessor
    Path D:\Logs\iotprocessor\Log*.log
    Skip_Empty_Lines On
    Skip_Long_Lines On
    Ignore_Older 1h

[FILTER]
    Name modify
    Match iotprocessor
    Add hostname ${COMPUTERNAME}
    Add application iotprocessor

[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Tag iottransformer
    Path D:\Logs\iottransformer\Log*.log
    Skip_Empty_Lines On
    Skip_Long_Lines On
    Ignore_Older 1h

[FILTER]
    Name modify
    Match iottransformer
    Add hostname ${COMPUTERNAME}
    Add application iottransformer


[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Tag iotformatter
    Path D:\Logs\iotformatter\Log*.log
    Skip_Empty_Lines On
    Skip_Long_Lines On
    Ignore_Older 1h

[FILTER]
    Name modify
    Match iotformatter
    Add hostname ${COMPUTERNAME}
    Add application iotformatter

[FILTER]
    Name grep
    Match *
    Exclude log /.*Catalog.*/

[OUTPUT]
    Name newrelic
    Match *
    licenseKey mylicencekeyforNewRelic
```

I can see logs are appearing in New Relic but eventually they seize to appear. On the host, I can see fluent-bit.exe is running and memory is increasing gradually (800MB +).

Would a local database to track monitored files help here. Also, can I specify a single DB for all  tail inputs or each one needs its own instance to avoid database locking?

```
DB C:\Program Files\fluent-bit\iotprocesser.db
```